# Counting corners of a polygon

Tags: arcmap, polygon

I have a square polygon with 4 sides, but the starting point is in the middle of a line between two corners of the square. If I count the vertices with the Python script !shape!.pointcount I get the answer 6 points
(start and ending point is counted double). How can I simplify the polygon that the result is 5. or count corners that have an angle of 90 degrees?

Comment: You mean you want to skip the first vertex, and replace the last with the second?

Comment: You said it: simplify the polygon with a small tolerance and the vertex from the middle of a segment should disappear.

Comment: Not tried this as I don't have your data but try running it through bounding geometry tool extracting the envelope, The envelope of a square is itself but may be the tool constructs the envelope starting from the corner? Don't know that tool, search the help file.